# decrement of right css by 4.5px for ever 10px decrement of width

Tags: javascript, css

I have a code for which the  is on right of page. it is fixed there by css as follows:

```
#feedback
{
position: absolute;
width: 230px;
float: right;
height: 60px;
right: 310px;
top: 190px;
}
```

but when the window size is resized the cs property 'right' should also reduce as this div is not visible if window is minimized than 100%

Initially 
`$( window ).width() = 1899px;`
'right' property for feedback div should be 310px

For every reduce of 10px in window width, right css of feedback div should reduce by 4.5px
egg.

```
Width = 1899px  Right property = 310px
```

Width = 1889px  Right property = 305.5px
Width = 1879px  Right property = 301px

.
.
.
.
util
Width = 1234px  Right property = 0px

I'm not able to make this logic work. Can anyone please help

Comment: 1 - 0.5px doesn't exist, think of pixels as integers. 2 - Please show what you have attempted, what has not worked.

Comment: reducing by 4px will also do

Comment: So not going to give us what you have done? Mmmkay, you need to rethink how we could possibly help you is you are not willing to give us anything.

Comment: Hi Dan , I have thought of logic as below var maxwidth = 1895; var maxright = 320; var currentWidth = $(window).width(); var currentRight = ''; var diff; maxwidth - currentWidth = diff; currentRight = maxright -((diff/10) * 4);

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with css only, using % values and margin.

[See the jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1v9kby9t/1/)

In my example, the internal element has a margin-right of 10%. This means that as the container changes width the offset from the right changes in size too, as does the internal element.

The container width is a % too so it flexes as the window flexes.

The css is here:

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
}

.internal {
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
    margin-right: 10%;
}
```

It's important to note that the internal margin-right value is a % of the container, not the element it belongs to.

To fix the width of the internal element just use a fixed width, the margin will still use the container width and keep it spaced relative to the width of the container.

See the [second JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tonileigh/1v9kby9t/2/). The only change is `width: 300px;` instead of `width: 50%;` on the internal.

Comment: Hi Toni, but this is reducind teh width of my div too

Comment: Hi Dan White , I have thought of login below
var maxwidth = 1895;
var maxright = 320;
var currentWidth = $(window).width();
var currentRight = '';
var diff;
maxwidth - currentWidth  = diff;

currentRight = maxright -((diff/10) * 4);